# Access array of elements panel overlay using Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, overlay, react, panel

[image: map2]

[image: map]

How do I get an array of elements (**id, checked**) that are checked in the panel?

Example: I need the list of **"talhão"** that are checked===true.

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react'

import L from 'leaflet'
import { MapContainer, LayersControl, GeoJSON } from 'react-leaflet'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
import 'leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw.css'

import {
  GoogleSatelite,
  OpenStreetMap_Mapnik,
  Osm
} from '../../core/map-providers/providers'
import { sendRequest } from '../../api/api-rest'
import { BASEURL } from '../../service'

const MapGrid = (props: any) => {
  const [center, setCenter] = useState({ lat: -17.8916, lng: -51.7406 })
  const layerControlRef = useRef<L.Control.Layers>(null)
  const [plots, setPlots] = useState(null)
  const [thereisPlots, setThereisPlots] = useState(false)
  const ZOOM_LEVEL = 12

  const onClick = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setThereisPlots(false)
    setPlots(null)
    const retorno = await sendRequest({
      url: `${BASEURL}/test`
    })

    if (retorno) {
      const lat = retorno[0].centroid.coordinates[1]
      const lng = retorno[0].centroid.coordinates[0]
      setCenter({ lat: lat, lng: lng })
      setPlots(retorno)
      setThereisPlots(true)
    }
  }

  const Plots = () => {
    if (thereisPlots === true) {
      return (
        <>
          {plots.map((item) => {
            const newidly = `${item.plotid}ly`
            const newidgj = `${item.plotid}ly`
            return (
              <LayersControl.Overlay
                key={newidly}
                checked={true}
                name={item.description}
              >
                <GeoJSON
                  key={newidgj}
                  data={item.geom}
                  eventHandlers={{
                    click: (e) => {
                      console.log('Event handler')
                      console.log(e)
                    }
                  }}
                />
              </LayersControl.Overlay>
            )
          })}
        </>
      )
    } else return null
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h2 className={'content-block'}>Map</h2>

      <div>
        <MapContainer
          center={center}
          zoom={ZOOM_LEVEL}
          scrollWheelZoom={true}
          style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}
        >
          <LayersControl
            position="topright"
            ref={layerControlRef}
            collapsed={false}
          >
            <LayersControl.BaseLayer checked name="Maps">
              <Osm />
              <GoogleSatelite />
              <OpenStreetMap_Mapnik />
            </LayersControl.BaseLayer>
            <Plots />
          </LayersControl>
        </MapContainer>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={onClick}>Get Data from Farm</button>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default MapGrid
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with React, but I can provide answer in vanilla Leaflet if that's OK with you.

Comment: Yes. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not familiar with React, answer will be for vanilla Leaflet JS.

One possibility to get list of overlay from layers control is to use internal control property `._layers`, which contains an array of objects, one for each layer in the control. Each object has three properties: `.name` for layer name in the control, `.layer` is actual layer, and `.overlay`, which is `true` for overlays.

If layer control would be defined/created like this:

```
var overlayLayers = {
  "layer1": layer1,
  "layer2": layer2
};

layerControl = L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlayLayers, {position: 'topleft', collapsed: false });
```

then function for creating array of all checked overlays could look like this:

```
function getCheckedOverlays() {
  var checkedOverlays = [];
  layerControl._layers.forEach(function(layer) {
    if (layer.overlay && map.hasLayer(layer.layer)) {
      checkedOverlays.push({'name': layer.name, 'layer': layer.layer});
    }
  });
  return(checkedOverlays);
}
```

Since practice of using library internals is not recommended one, it would be better to use `overlayLayers` object, used to define overlays for the layers ontrol, to iterate though overlays:

```
function getCheckedOverlays2() {
  var checkedOverlays = [];
  for (let overlayName in overlayLayers) {
    var overlay = overlayLayers[overlayName];
    if (map.hasLayer(overlay)) {
      checkedOverlays.push({'name': overlayName, 'layer': overlay});
    }
  }
  return(checkedOverlays);
}
```